# Prove that $|A+A|=2n-1$ if and only if the sequence $A$ is an AP.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Let $A$ be a non empty finite sequence of $n$ distinct integers $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$. Define $|A+A|=\{a_i+a_j | 1 \le i,j \le n\}$ e.g. for $A=\{1,4\}$, $A+A=\{2,5,8\}$

Prove that $|A+A|=2n-1$ if and only if the sequence $A$ is an AP.

My approach is for any fixed number $k\in [2,2n], \    a_i+a_{k-i}$ is constant. So, if choose an AP it is easy to show that $A+A$ will have $2n-1$ elements. My query is how to prove the converse.

Comment: I think you mean $A+A = \{a_i+a_j \mid 1 \le i,j \le n\}$.  $|A+A|$ is the cardinality of that set.

Comment: Yes, it is cardinality which I forgot to mention

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to find $2n - 1$ different elements in $A + A$:
$$a_1 + a_1 < a_1 + a_2 < a_1 + a_3 < \dots < a_1 + a_n < a_2 + a_n < a_3 + a_n < \dots < a_n + a_n.$$

Thus if $|A + A| = 2n - 1$, then these must be all elements of $A + A$.

Now what happens to the other sums?

E.g. we may also create the following $2n - 1$ elements:
$$a_1 + a_1 < a_1 + a_2 < a_2 + a_2 < a_2 + a_3 < \dots < a_2 + a_n < a_3 + a_n < \dots < a_n + a_n.$$

Comment: That's precisely what I was thinking, but I was thinking of induction

Comment: I hadn't seen this before - it's a great argument!

Comment: @Mathsmerizing what do you mean from your post that a_i + a_k-i is constant ? As such its doesnt look like it will ever be constant isnt ?